# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4+3^n}{2^n}$ convergent or divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4+3^n}{2^n}$

$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4+3^n}{2^n} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{2^n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^n}{2^n} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{2 \cdot 2^{n-1}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{3}{2}\bigg)^n \\
&= 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{2} \bigg(\frac{3}{2}\bigg)^{n-1}
\end{align}$

Now I observe that the two terms are both geometric series and although the first one converges because $\frac{1}{2} < 1$, the second one doesn't because $\frac{3}{2} > 1$. Then can I assume that the series diverges and that is it?

Comment: Don't even bother with all of that.  Look at the limit of the summands... $\frac{4+3^n}{2^n}$, as $n$ gets large $4$ will get dwarfed in size by $3^n$, so this acts like $\frac{3^n}{2^n}$ which acts like $(\frac{3}{2})^n$ which grows without bound.  Since the summands don't approach zero the series trivially diverges.

Comment: Yes, u can just use that it is a series of positive terms and $\frac{4+3^n}{2^n} > \frac{3^n}{2^n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Whenever you have a convergent series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and a divergent  series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_n+b_n)$ diverges.

Or you can apply the ratio test to reach the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct!

You can also argue that $
\frac{4+3^{n}}{2^{n}} \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \infty
$ that is the necessary condition for a series to converge doesn't hold in our case that is- the limit of a sequence defining a convergent series is $0$. Or the limit of a general term in the series is $0$. Or as peter kindly commented-  the sequence of the summands to converge to  $0$.

Comment: ... and that necessary condition is the sequence of the summands to converge to $0$.